# How to handle requests with unsupported content type correctly?

Tags: rest, exception, jersey, jax-rs

I have a REST interface build with Jersey. Actually I only support as content type only `application/json` for all incoming requests. That is why I defined my message body reader and writer as

```java
@Provider
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class MarshallerProvider
    implements MessageBodyReader<Object>, MessageBodyWriter<Object>
{
}
```

Now I wrote a test where I try to get a document via GET and expected content type `application/xml`. Jersey answers this request with an `MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException`.

So what would be the best way to handle such unsupported requests correctly? Should I write an exception mapper? Since it is an internal exception I don't like this approach?

The solution should allow me to return an HTTP 415 (Unsupported Media Type).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, avoid exception handlers, handle this case with methods:

```java
@Path("example")
public class Example {

  @GET
  public Response getBadStuff() {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE).build();
  }

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Object getGoodStuff() {
    return myObject;
  }
}
```

Comment: The reason for my problem is the `@Consumes` annotation on `MarshallerProvider`. Therefor Jersey is unable to find a message body provider. If I remove this annotation I get a 406 error. Which is the correct error code for sending a request with an unsupported content type. 
So I will give you an upvote, correct my question and provide the correct answer to the corrected question.